# Get XML request file processed during service call

Tags: asp.net, xml, wcf, web-services, soap

We have third party service and writing below code to execute. After adding its service reference it gives us object.

```
client objClient = new client();
info objEntities = new info();

objEntities.reginfo = new reginfoRequest();

response objResp = objClient.registerInfo(objEntities);
```

I have enabled Diagnostic and it records XML in .svclog file.

** But what I want to do is.. I want to record each XML file during processing and record each XML file in specific folder.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What about using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) ?

There you can see all requests and responses.